# No puedo guardar variables string dentro de una variable string

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy trabajando un un proyecto de Laravel y Tengo el siguiente código donde tengo que crear horas, para después guardarlas en una variable en un array, antes de hacer esto cambio el Objecto DateTime a string con el método **format()** pero me lanza la siguiente exepción

Código:

```
    //crea un objecto
   $date = new DateTime('08:00');
   // devuelve un string
   $date->format('H:i:s');

   //crea un objecto
   $date2 = new DateTime('09:00');
   $date2->modify('+5 minute');
   // devuelve un string
   $date2->format('H:i:s');

   $block = "$date - $date2";

   return $block;
```

Exepción:

```
ErrorException
Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

Me segure de que el método **format()** devuelva un string haciendo un:

```
return gettype($date);
```

Y el output es **string** y sin embargo no me deja guardar **$date** y **$date2** dentro de $block ya que me lanza la exepción antes mencionada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta sobreescribir el valor de la variable con el dato tipo `string`.

```php
//crea un objecto
$date = new DateTime('08:00');
// $date->format('H:i:s') devuelve un string pero debes guardarlo en la variable
$date = $date->format('H:i:s');

//crea un objecto
$date2 = new DateTime('09:00');
$date2->modify('+5 minute');
// $date2->format('H:i:s') devuelve un string pero debes guardarlo en la variable
$date2 = $date2->format('H:i:s');

// luego todo bien
$block = "$date - $date2";

return $block;
```

Comment: Wou muchisimas gracias.